# 404 Errors only with .aspx extensions

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis

I have a .NET 2.0 application running on IIS 6.

When I choose the browse option on `.gif` and `.txt` files they appear in the browser. When I choose to browse to any `.aspx` page, I get a `404 error not found`.

The site is an IIS application and the `bin` directory has the required `.dll` files.

There are no events in the event log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open command window

navigate to the location where the .NET framework is installed

Could look like this

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>
```

Register the asp.net mappings with

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727> aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable
```

Comment: Thanks Greco, I tried that and still all ASPX pages give a simple 404. all other resources work fine. Did an iisreset as well after the regiis

Comment: .NET 2,and 3.5 are installed on the box

Comment: The application configuration has .aspx pointing to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll for GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG

Comment: I had to also enable ASPX under "Web Service Extensions"

Comment: Your `aspnet_regiis.exe -i` should be `aspnet_regiis.exe -i -enable` to register and enable the Web Service Extension.

Answer (score 2):

You might have to enable .NET:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;332124&Product=winsvr2003

Or, in IIS management, under web service extensions, you should check if ASP.NET v2.0.50727 is set to allowed.